# Customize image upload field in simple form & carrierwave

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, image-uploading, simple-form

I've been struggling with customization of the simple form field for image upload (Carrierwave) in my Rails app.

[Current design:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM99n.png)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crz93.png)

What I did was to inspect HTML created by simple form helpers:

```
<%= f.input :photo %>
<%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %>
```

add styling, remove unnecessary fields and icons, which resulted in:

```
<label class="btn file-upload-btn">
 <div class="form-group file required event_photo upload-field">
  <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
   Add a photo
   <div class="form-control uneditable-input input-name" data-trigger="fileinput">
    <i class="fa fa-file fileinput-exists"></i>
    <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group-btn"  style="display: none;">
    <input class="file required file-upload" type="file" name="event[photo]" id="event_photo">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <span style="display:none;">
  <%= f.input :photo_cache, as: :hidden %>
 </span>
</label>
```

Button works properly - I can select the picture, name tag shows to chosen img name. However when I try to submit the form it gives an error that image can't be blank.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please remove the "image-processing" tag, your question has nothing to do with image processing.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use Image upload widget included in Jasny gem : http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/

And customize the input, like with user photo :

```
 <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
  <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
     <input type="file" name="user[photo]" id="user_photo">
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll be free to customize the css to have this like me :

[image]

It's working on my project.